# C++ Any way to print maximum double (8 bytes) value with full precision without changing it to long long?

Tags: c++, calculator

I have an issue when printing the value with 'cout'. I would like to see value "9223372036854775807" in console but I just keep on getting "9223372036854775800" and same happens with negative values. I also want user to enter this as a maximum value and want to keep decimal places.

--------------- these will be the minimum and maximum value

```
double al = scnd_num_min(num1, Oprt);
al = al * (-1);
double ah = scnd_num_max(num1, Oprt);
```

-------------- and this is where I print these values

```
cout << "Please enter a value within a range of: " << "\n" << fixed << al;
cout << " and " << ah << " : ";
```

And that is one function to get value:

```
    double scnd_num_max(double num1, char Oprt)
    {
    double max1 = 9223372036854775807;
    double max2 = 9223372036854775806;
    double min1 = -9223372036854775806;
    switch(Oprt)
    {
    case '+':
        if (num1 <= 0)
            return max1;
        else
            return (max1 - num1);
    case '-':
        if (num1 >= -1)
            return max1;
        else
            return ((max1 - (num1 * (-1)))+1);
    case '*':
        if ((num1 < min1) || (num1 > max2))
            return 1;
        else if (num1 == 0)
            return max2;
        else if (num1 > 0)
            return (max2 / num1);
        else
            return (max2 / (num1 * (-1)));
    case '/':
        return max2;
    }
}
```

Pretty same is for negative value.

Comment: Helpful reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) TL;DR version: You can only fit so much in a floating point variable  before losing precision For a `double` this is about 15 digits. 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 is 19 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double is 64 bit wide, but it cannot hold every value that a long long (also 64bit) can hold, because a floating point number consists of a sign bit, an exponent and a mantissa. The mantissa for double is 52bit wide, so you can be sure that every 52bit (actually 53 because of the sign bit) wide integer can be stored without loss of precision in a double, for the rest you may loose precision.

edit: By the way, double max is 1.79769e+308, see [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)

Comment: Okay then I will put 1.79769e+308 as max but I just want to know is there a way to increase that bit size in c++?

Comment: @TourerPovilas No, you cannot increase the number of bits in a double, nor can you change the subdivision into mantissa and exponent. What you can do is to use a library such as [this](https://gmplib.org/)